# Can I output the Placeholder Text of a plain text matrix block?

Tags: templating, matrix

Is there a way to output the Placeholder Text of a plaintext field if there's no specific value entered to the Entry?

(Am I missing something — should it happen automatically if there's no specific value entered?)

[The docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/plain-text-fields) say: "The text that will be shown if the field does't have a value" — does `shown` just mean in the form on the Entry form in the admin, or also on the front-end as a value of block.FIELDNAME ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "docs" means only on the admin form. For outputing a default text on empty fields in frontend you can use the following code in you template:

```
{{block.FIELDNAME | default("Placeholdertext") }}
```